# how do i search 4 character of comma seperated string in to my specific table and more than 4 character word in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My inputs are as follows:

1. **Plas,Plaster,elec,electrical**
2. **ipad**

i am having 2 table:

1. **UserDetails**:FirstName,**ServiceDescription**,**Skills**
2. **CategoryMaster**:ID,**Name**

I am splitting the string by comma and matching one by one word in to my 2 tables on fields **ServiceDescription**,**Skills**,**Name**(Category name).

So now when my input string contain comma then i want 4 character word in my string to be match in CategoryMaster Table only on **Name** field.

**Like for input 1**:

> Plas:Match on **Name**  field only of CategoryMaster Table.
>
> Plaster:Match on **ServiceDescription**,**Skills**,**Name**
>
> elec:Match on **Name**  field only of CategoryMaster Table.

**For input 2**:

As My 2nd input does not contain any comma means it is a whole word then:

> ipad:Match on **Name**  field only of CategoryMaster Table.

Eg:

input 1:word **Plas**

```
 WHERE c.Name LIKE '%plas%'
```

input 1:word **Plaster**

```
WHERE ((u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%plaster%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%plaster%') OR 
                                  (c.Name LIKE '%plaster%')
```

this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchworkerProcedure]
    @SearchKeyword nvarchar(70)

AS
    DECLARE @I INT
        DECLARE @keyname nvarchar(50)
        DECLARE @totalRecords INT


    DECLARE @Keywords TABLE
   (    
      sno INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      keyname VARCHAR(100) ,
      isSplitted int
    )

    DECLARE @SearchKeywordTable TABLE
    (
        [VendorId] [int]  NULL,
            [ServiceDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
            [Skills] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    )
 INSERT INTO @Keywords SELECT * FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword,@sep)

BEGIN   
        IF (len(@SearchKeyword) > 0)
            BEGIN           
                SELECT @I = 1
                SELECT @totalRecords = COUNT(*) FROM @Keywords
                WHILE (@I <= @totalRecords)
                BEGIN
                    SET @keyname = (SELECT keyname FROM @Keywords WHERE sno = @I)   
                    Insert INTO @SearchKeywordTable                                     
                        SELECT *
                        FROM UserDetails u 
                        INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
                        INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id 
                        WHERE (
                        (len(@keyname) > 0) and
                        (u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%') OR 
                                  (c.Name LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%')
                                  )
                        ORDER BY ISNULL(r.RatingValue, 0) DESC;         
                        SELECT @I = @I + 1 

                END
                SELECT DISTINCT VendorId,*  FROM @SearchKeywordTable                    
            END
```

Anybody can help please?????

Comment: you hv not mention from which position to substring 4 charector.Like if input is "Plaster" then 4 char will be Plas,ster or what ?

Comment: i am passing this string from server side where my logic is if string length is greater than 4 then split string by 4 character and and append this 4 character to original string:eg original string is plaster then split plaster by 4 character so it will become plas and append this to my original string with comma so final string becomes:plas,plaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of while.Remove uneccsary table and column from this proc.It should work .It is faster than previous query and but can be still slower if lot of record because of several reason like

- LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%' instead us only LIKE @keyname+'%' and create
  non CI on those columns
- Use Full-text search (read in msdn)

> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchworkerProcedure]
>           @SearchKeyword nvarchar(70)
>
> ```
> AS
> DECLARE @I INT
>
> DECLARE @keyname nvarchar(50)
>
> DECLARE @totalRecords INT
>
> DECLARE @Keywords TABLE
>    (    
>       sno INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>       keyname VARCHAR(100) ,
>       Shortkeyname as  substring(keyname,0,4),
>       isSplitted int
>     )
>
> DECLARE @SearchKeywordTable TABLE
> (
>     [VendorId] [int]  NULL,
>         [ServiceDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
>         [Skills] [nvarchar](max) NULL
> )  INSERT INTO @Keywords SELECT * FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword,@sep)
> ```
>
> BEGIN
>
> ```
>                     SELECT *
>                     FROM UserDetails u 
>                     INNER JOIN VendorInCategory v ON v.VendorId=u.Id 
>                     INNER JOIN CategoryMaster c ON v.CategoryId=c.Id
>                     CROSS APPLY ( SELECT * FROM @Keywords)Fn
>                     WHERE 
>                     (u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%'+Fn.keyname+'%') OR (u.Skills LIKE '%'+Fn.keyname+'%') 
>                     OR c.Name LIKE '%'+Fn.Shortkeyname+'%')
>
>                     ORDER BY ISNULL(r.RatingValue, 0) DESC;     
>                     --wht is  RatingValue ?it is in which table.   
>
>
>
>                     END
> ```

Comment: i cant use full text search because full text search wont work on azure becauase for free textsearch we have to buy license so i would strictly have to use like only

Comment: i am splitting one by one word by comma and storing in keyword table and then searching in userdetail and category tbale so will this work without while loop???

Comment: @mariapithia,it will work 100% .May be lil syntax error that you hv to fix .Thats it .So if lot of record to return then use paging.

Comment: @mariapithia ,first get it working.Is it working ?where is the problem ?see my code,insert into Keywords (keyname,isSplitted) values('plaster',0)

Comment: Yup it is working but on which column i have to create non ci and why?

Comment: @mariapithia ,I was just trying to to say to increase performance you can create non cluster index on ServiceDescription,Skill, Name.
how many avg rows will be return and whether this proc is very important  ?

Comment: this procedure can return many records like you can say more than 1000 records atleast and this proc is very very important so please please if you can tell me how do i create noncluster index on servicedescription,skills and name????  and the solution you had provide was a sign of genuis

Answer (score 0):

you can write like :

```
WHERE 1 = case when len(@keyname) = 4 and c.Name LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%' then 1 
               when (u.ServiceDescription LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%') 
                    OR (u.Skills LIKE '%'+@keyname+'%') then 1 end
```

Comment: can u please write while loop logic please because i am having lots of problem with store procedure syntax as because this is my first store procedure